# how to create conda environment from within Miniconda

Tags: python, conda, miniconda, virtual-environment

I have Anaconda3 (Python 3.7) install on my MacOS.  For specific project, I installed Miniconda3 (Python 3.6).  I would like to install packages with Miniconda but whenever I create new conda environment, it installs it within the Anaconda3 and uses python 3.7.  How can i change this?

Comment: If you have an Anaconda installation and you want an environment with Python 3.6 instead of the default version, you just specify that when you create the env (`conda create -n mynewenv python=3.6`). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package manager in Anaconda and Miniconda are identical (Conda), so there is no need install Miniconda in your system if you intend to keep Anaconda. Creating envs with

```
conda create -n myenv python some_packages
```

will have the same result either way with the exception that they maintain different package caches - hence you only have a downside by installing both. Remove one, and you probably also need to clean up your shell initialization script (e.g., `.bash_profile`), since the installers edit this.